# How to get to chest near Desert Area?

Tags: nier-automata

As you're heading to the Desert Camp, if you follow the row of building to your left *away* from the camp and have the chip that shows item locations, there's a chest which is locked and you need 9S to open it. I can't figure out how to get to the top of the building on which it's located, though. There's a building across the street which you can get to by jumping on a bus then climbing on an A/C unit, but you can't jump/float far enough to reach the building.

[image: Chest circled in red]
[image: Marked on map. The transit to the right is the Desert camp]

Comment: Could you post a picture?

Comment: @Vemonus Yup, I'll do that later today.

Comment: @Vemonus Added a few pictures.

Comment: I don't recall this exact chest, but did you try doing a sprint + jump + jump + glide + attack + glide? That's the way to get the absolute most distance out of a jump.

Comment: @Vemonus Ok, I found a video that shows attacking __while__ holding the pod can make the android move up & forward, so if you want to detail that in an answer I'd accept it.  A video with explanation of the technic would be ideal :-)

Comment: yeah, I was going to try when I got home. I'll post a descriptive answer now and update with a video if I have time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't encountered this exact chest yet, but the distance looks like it's definitely doable by jumping, though you have to do a special combo to maximize your distance.

In addition to sprinting, double jumping, and gliding with your Pod, attacking (square) once will thrust you upwards and forwards a bit, which should propel you to the other building.

---

I've since found the chest, so here is a video of me jumping to it:

Comment: I love how 9S is standing right next to 2B and refuses to open the chest. :-)

Comment: Also, this jump is harder with 9S since his sword skills are embarrassing compared to 2B.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble with mid-air combos, there's another way to boost your jumping distance:

> Pod program A160: Missile, obtainable during route C (NG++). You can charge it for an extended boost. http://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/A160:+Missile

Answer (score -2):

Fist 40.  Jump, hold x, while holding x press square, sq, sq,  r2, x to jump, holding x square.  Should clear it by half a building.